# Zend Framework: Download?

Tags: zend-framework, download

I am new to zend. Downloaded the zend framework from the zend site. Now how do i generate the zend folder structure like applications, bin, public folders!? What's the best way to generate the folder structure?

Thanks.

Comment: you could at least have a look at the zend framework documentation before asking : http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/learning.quickstart.create-project.html

Comment: First check the manual then google the hundreds of tutorials out there.

Comment: Well thanks! I've read the manual! Thats why i've asked for the best way..!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Think about your application structure, if you want to make an application with fore-end and back-end (two modules) or even more, you should better try modules in Zend framework. I have written a post for that, but no details on it. http://www.bang58.co.cc/blog/zend-framework-module-website-structure/

I think you can check this to know the basic application structure of Zend framework - http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/learning.quickstart.intro.html

And then, you can check this to know how to use module in your application - http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.controller.modular.html

Comment: You are welcome, I am glad it helps also glad to know you Vish!

Answer (score 0):

This really depends on your needs. As Tom wrote, modules as the way when your app is going to be more complex than some feel controllers.

I've created a default structure for my projects based on modules. The idea is to centralize basic controllers in default module, and every else in specific ones, thinking in reuse.

Some examples:

My dir structure:

```
application
|--configs
   | config.ini
|--modules
| bootstrap.php
lib
|--MyLib
   |--locales
|--Zend
public
|--js
|--css
|--etc ...
```

Very like Tom's article. Some diferences are put in the config.ini:

```
#My locales are in the MyLib dir
resources.translate.data = LIB_PATH "/Agana/locales"
resources.translate.scan = "directory"

#My default module has another name
resources.frontController.controllerDirectory = APPLICATION_PATH "/modules/aganacore/controllers"
resources.frontController.moduleDirectory = APPLICATION_PATH "/modules"
resources.frontController.prefixDefaultModule = true 
resources.frontController.defaultModule = aganacore

#My IndexController from default module redirect to this config variable
myproject.defaulturl = "dashboard"
```

In my IndexController this is my indexAction:

```
public function indexAction() {
    // this call gets the myproject option in config.ini, please search how to get bootstrap options
    $options = Mylib_Util_Bootstrap::getOption('myproject');

    if (isset($options['defaulturl'])) {
        if (trim($options['defaulturl']) != '') {
            $this->_redirect($options['defaulturl']);
        }
    }
}
```

Well, this is a part of the whole structure, but I believe it's enough to help you start.

Best regards.